# $4qx^3-3qx-p$ is not reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Show $4qx^3-3qx-p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $\gcd(p,q)=1$, $q>1$, and $q$ is cubefree.

This question is closely related to trisecting an angle is impossible under certain conditions.

Comment: What is $a$? *Any* $a\in{\Bbb Z}$ with $|a|>1$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: $q$ **never** will be divisible by **all** the $2^3,\ 3^3,\cdots,n^3,\cdots$.

Comment: Just say it's cubefree.

Comment: Clearly the OP means "cubefree"...since otherwise a chance of variable would land you in this case.

Comment: $q$ cubefree $\leftrightarrow\forall a>0(\lnot a^3|q)$. I think what you're saying is $\lnot\forall a>0(a^3|q)$.

Comment: @Kaa1el Who are you talking to? Please specify.

Comment: I can't edit it. I was talking to Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla.

Comment: @Kaa1el yes, cubefree is divisible by **none** of $2^3,\ 3^3,\cdots,n^3,\cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's reducible, it must have a root, which root we'll write as $r/s$, a quotient of two integers in lowest terms. So $$4qr^3-3qrs^2-ps^3=0$$ Now let $t$ be a prime dividing $q$. Then $t$ must divide $ps^3$, but $\gcd(p,q)=1$, so $t$ divides $s^3$, so $t$ divides $s$, so $t^3$ divides $s^3$. Then $t^3$ also divides $3qrs^2$, so it divides $q$. This contradicts the assumption on $q$, so $q$ is not divisible by any prime; we must have $q=\pm1$.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Gerry, I'm not sure this is completely correct. What if $t = 2$?

Comment: @user, well-spotted. I would make a correction, but as you have already posted a solution, I don't feel the need.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) := 4qx^3 - 3qx - p$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it has a rational root $a/b$ (and WLOG $b \in \mathbb{N}$, $\text{gcd}(a,b) = 1$). By the rational root theorem, $a \mid p$, $b \mid 4q$. We have $4q(\frac{a}{b})^3 - 3q(\frac{a}{b}) - p = 0$, and to bring the middle term to $\mathbb{Z}$, we multiply by $4$, to get $16q(\frac{a}{b})^3 = 12q(\frac{a}{b}) + 4p$. Then the RHS is an integer, so $b^3 \mid 16qa^3 \implies b^3 \mid 16q \implies b \mid 2$. Since $f(x)$ has no integer roots (since $\frac{p}{q} \not \in \mathbb{Z}$), $b = 2$, but then $4q(\frac{a}{2})^3 - 3q(\frac{a}{2}) - p = 0$, so $q(a^3 - 3a) = 2p$. But $a^3 - 3a$ is always even, so $p = q(\frac{a^3 - 3a}{2})$, contradicting $\text{gcd}(p,q) = 1$.

As you noted, this shows exactly that if $\cos(\theta) = \frac{p}{q}$ ($p$ and $q$ as above), then $\theta$ is not trisectable.